# Listview else statement showing long list

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3TXN.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4QAO.png)i have created a listview. when i apply a filter i want to show only data in that particular condition. if no item present in the condition i want to show a text with a message saying "NO BOOKING NOW".

i got all well , but "NO BOOKING NOW" showing multiple times like in a list. I want to display only once .

my code is below

```
                    : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _bookingData.bookingData == null
                    ?  Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
                    : _bookingData.bookingData.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>BookingDetails(_bookingData.bookingData[index]
                      )));},
                      child: (widget.formattedDate == null&&widget.bookId == null) ?
                               // List()


                      ListPopUP(_bookingData.bookingData[index])




                          : ((widget.formattedDate != null&&(_bookingData.bookingData[index].date.toString().contains(widget.formattedDate)))?





                      ListPopUP(_bookingData.bookingData[index]):





                      (widget.bookId != null&&_bookingData.bookingData[index].bookingId.toString().contains(widget.bookId))?





                      ListPopUP(_bookingData.bookingData[index]):




                      Container(
                        child: Text("NO BOOKING NOW"),
                      )),
                    ) ;

                })),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your condition is, for time being I have assumed it as *show*

```
bool show = false;
    int n = 10;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: show?ListView.builder(
        itemCount: n,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
              child: Text('Your statement you wanted')
            ),
          );
        },
      ):Container(
                        child: Text("NO BOOKING NOW"),
                      ),
```